# Deriving Probability

Tags: probability

John is interested in an anticipated rise in A. The probability that both a rise in A and B will occur is 20% and there is a joint probability of 30% that A will not increase and B will increase. John thinks there is a 60% probability that A will increase. If A do not increase, what is the probability that B will increase?

> Given: P (A↑ ∩ B↑) = 0.20; P (A no ↑ ∩ B↑) = 0.30; P (A↑) = 0.60
>
> Find: P (B↑| A no ↑)
>
> Therefore: P (A↑ ∩ B↑) =  P (A↑) * P (B↑) -> 0.20 = 0.60 * P (B↑) -> P (B↑) =  1/3
>
> P (A no ↑ ∩ B↑) = P (A no ↑) * P (B↑) -> 0.30 =  P(A no ↑) * 1/3 -> P(A no ↑) = 0.90
>
> My solution: P (B↑ | A no ↑) = (B↑ ∩ A no ↑) / P (A no ↑) = (1/3 * 0.90) / 0.90 = 0.30 / 0.90
>
> P (B↑ | A no ↑) = 1/3

I am doubtful whether I should use the complement rule in finding the probability that A will not increase (so, it is 1 - 0.60 = 0.40), instead of 0.90 obtained through the joint probability.

Comment: Yes. I just arrived at my 'what if' because my probability of 1/3 is marked incorrect. I assume there must be something wrong with my computation.

Comment: I misread the question...withdrew my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you write $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$, which is false unless the corresponding events are independent. Below is the correct solution.

To make the notation more clear, write $A=1$ or $B =1$  if $A$ rises or $B$ rises and write $A = 0$ or $B=0$ if $A$ falls or $B$ falls.

Now, we have 
$$
P(A = 1, B = 1) = \frac{1}{5} \\
P(A = 0, B = 1) = \frac{3}{10} \\
P(A = 1) = \frac{6}{10} .
$$
Since probabilities must sum up to 1, we also have 
$$
P(A = 0) = \frac{4}{10}.
$$
Now, by the definition of joint probability, 
$$P(A = 0, B = 1) = P(B = 1 | A = 0) P(A = 0)$$
or
$$
P(B =1 | A = 0) = \frac{P(A = 0, B=1)}{P(A=0)} = \frac{ 3/10}{4/10} = \frac{3}{4}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, I wonder how to find P (B = 1) using the definition of probability, in place of using algebra.

Comment: No problem! You should try using the same approach to get P(B=1). It should be very similar...

Comment: One last thing. How do I know which one to use among the two: P(A ∩ B) = P (B|A) P(A) or  P(A ∩ B) = P (A|B) P(B), if the problem is silent regarding which event is dependent to which?

Comment: You should choose to use the one which you can compute using the information given in the problem

Comment: Many thanks for helping me out today! :)